# Run script before Bash exits

Tags: bash, exit, xfce

I'd like to run a script every time I close a Bash session.

I use XFCE and Terminal 0.4.5 (Xfce Terminal Emulator), I would like to run a script every time I close a tab in Terminal including the last one (when I close Terminal).

Something like .bashrc but running at the end of every session.

.bash_logout doesn't work

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You use `trap` (see `man bash`):

```
trap /u1/myuser/on_exit_script.sh EXIT
```

The command can be added to your `.profile/.login`

This works whether you exit the shell normally (e.g. via `exit` command) or simply kill the terminal window/tab, since the shell gets the `EXIT` signal either way - I just tested by exiting my putty window.

Answer (score 11):

My answer is similar to [DVK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5033539/462015) but you have to use a command or function, not a file.

```
$ man bash

   [...]

   trap [-lp] [[arg] sigspec ...]
          The command arg is to be read and executed when the shell
          receives signal(s) sigspec.

          [...]

          If a sigspec is EXIT (0) the command arg is executed on
          exit from the shell.
```

So, you can add to your `.bashrc` something like the following code:

```
finish() {
  # Your code here
}

trap finish EXIT
```

Answer (score 3):

Write you script in "~/.bash_logout". It executed by bash(1) when login shell exits.

Comment: Note that this only works if bash is executed as a login shell, e.g. if you login via SSH or check "Run command as a login shell" in gnome-terminal's Profile Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

If you close your session with "exit", might be able to something like 
`alias endbash="./runscript;exit"` and just exit by entering endbash. I'm not entirely sure this works, as I'm running windows at the moment.

edit: DVK has a better answer.