# How to execute a script when xfce session ends

Tags: linux, xfce

Is it possible to run a script/command when the xfce session stops ?

Comment: you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033354/run-script-before-bash-exits

Comment: I saw this question too, but it would call the "endscript" for any script that I would launch.
In fact, if xfce-session were a script, I could do that but it is a compiled program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `/usr/bin/xfce4-session` executable with a shell script which runs the original `xfce4-session` and your logout script if `xfce4-session` finished.

```
# mv /usr/bin/xfce4-session /usr/bin/xfce4-session.orig
```

The new `/usr/bin/xfce4-session` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/xfce4-session.orig
echo "my logout script" > /tmp/testfile
```

Don't forget to set the execute permissions:

```
# chmod a+x /usr/bin/xfce4-session
```

(Tested on Debian Squeeze.)

Comment: I accepted the answer since it is a good idea, however I would have prefered a solution which does not impact distribution binary files.

Comment: See http://mail.xfce.org/pipermail/xfce/2012-November/031694.html - that is you can put the wrapper script in /usr/local/bin or another dir that precedes the dir where xfce4-session is installed, and not change /usr/bin/X11/xfce4-session. It's not perfect (depends on PATH order) but may be more palatable

Comment: Disadvantage: overwrite your new batch file each time an update for package `xfce4-settings` is installed.

Answer (score 5):

See http://mail.xfce.org/pipermail/xfce/2012-November/031694.html - There, Erik Habicht suggested creating a wrapper script in `/usr/local/bin/xfce4-session` (or another dir that precedes the dir where `xfce4-session` is installed, `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`). This way, you do not have to change `/usr/bin/X11/xfce4-session`, so it can be updated independently.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Add your own pre-session logic here
/usr/bin/xfce4-session
# Add your own logout logic here
```

then

```
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/xfce4-session
```

It's not perfect (depends on `PATH` order) but may be more palatable.

(*Note: I promoted my comment to an answer.*)

Comment: Finally a solution for xfce logout-hooks, thanks alot! ... maybe again add the hint "chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/xfce4-session" .. missing it caused me some trouble. I will open a xfce bug/feature request to automatically trigger a simple ~/.logout

Comment: One remaining problem: It looks like the solution only works if explicitly a "logout" is done. If I directly shutdown my system, the .logout script is not executed. (Distro: Debian Jessie)

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer solution that does not touch system directories or files and will run the logout hook within current user session and its privilledges.

below is my solution:

create `~/.local/bin/xfce4-session-logout` script with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
PRELOGOUT=${HOME}/scripts/pre-logout.sh

RESULT=RES_`echo -e "logout\nrestart\nshutdown\nsuspend" | zenity --height=250 --list --title "Logout from $USER" --column "What do You want to do?"`
case $RESULT in
    RES_logout)
        [ -x  $PRELOGOUT] && $PRELOGOUT
        /usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout --fast --logout
        ;;
    RES_restart)
        [ -x  $PRELOGOUT] && $PRELOGOUT
        /usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout --fast --reboot
        ;;
    RES_shutdown)
        [ -x  $PRELOGOUT] && $PRELOGOUT
        /usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout --fast --halt
        ;;
    RES_suspend)
        /usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout --suspend
        ;;
    *)
       exit 1
       ;;
esac
```

and make it executable:

```
chmod u+x ~/.local/bin/xfce4-session-logout
```

Now, put whatever You need to be executed at logout action to `~/scripts/pre-logout.sh` and make it executable

```
chmod u+x ~/scripts/pre-logout.sh
```

after relogin, either `menu > logout button` or `Alt+f3: "logout"` will bring simple dialog for leaving the current session

Note: pressing `Alt+F4` does not work with it, but maybe some black belted xfce4 users will provide some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I validated the answer above since it does not involve new code writing.
I however found another way to proceed : create a X11 program which would be launched at session startup : it could execute custom scripts when the X session is closed

Note : the drawback is that the used scripts could not connect to X windows so this solution may, depending on the need, execute the script too late.

Comment: how does a startup script handle the case of session ending? i.e. does it have to trap a signal, respond to an X event?

Comment: It can do what it wants when the real xfce-session ends : your script must launch it and then block until it terminates